# Best way to handle form that can be submitted using Ajax or the classic way?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a HTML form (written with Blade) that offers the user a way to subscribe to a newsletter. The request is sent using Ajax. Then I handle it using Laravel and the `api` middleware group. But if user disables JavaScript, then he or she cannot use the form, obviously nothing happens. I am trying to find a way to make the form work no matter if JavaScript is disabled or not.
My first thought was to use the `ajax()` method from the `Request` class. But I realized `$errors` is not passed to the session when using the `api` middleware group. I thought about not using the `api` middleware group or having two controllers, one for Ajax requests and another for classic HTTP requests.

I was wondering if someone already faced this challenge?

I am not sure if my question / problem is clear. If you have any questions please do not hesitate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Wah lucky me for ajax request that made by the application (laravel itself) I never use api middleware. Thanks for pointing this out. Anyways, how about extending api guard to also populate session? Will it suit such needs?

Comment: I thought about it too because It is pretty easy to do. Is it good practice? Should I even be using the `api` middleware group in the first place?

Comment: Currently I'm with an app with nearly 400 routes. As far as I can say, as you separate each routes (group) wisely, everything's just ... best practice. Anyways, the `api` middleware is by default, baked to do authentication with custom header which I can say, needed if you're creating a fullstack client side api consumer apps. Let's say an angular app, which you should never worried off about "what if javascript disabled". So I must say that in this case, extending the guard to handle some logic is good idea, too.

Comment: What about the user, how'd you authenticate them in the first place? Do they have stored in session? If so, calling `Auth::guard('session')->user()` or something like that is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used a submit button with java script called on submit to post by ajax and in the posting code added an Ajax property.

If jave script is disabled the submit button will post the form (no java script to override that function) and as the ajax property is not set this can be detected on the server and dealt with accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That is how I am dealing with it client-side. My question is more a server-side question. How should I organize my controller(s) and handle errors?